# Android приложение падает при получении данных из сети

Tags: java, android, отладка

Приложение получает данные от вебсервиса. Процедура получения данных запускается в сервисе. На устройстве с Android 4.4.0 всё работает корректно. На эмуляторе, под Android 6.0 падает.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap_request);
soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;


List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ Base64.encode(loginpassword.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))));        
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,120000);
transport.debug = true;

transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope, headers);
```

Падение происходит не сразу, а через несколько секунд после запуска запроса. Приблизительно это похоже на время которое нужно серверу для ответа.
Буду рад, если пнете в нужном направлении.

Лог очень большой, поэтому приведу только начало:

```
08-23 08:56:32.091 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/compiler/dex/mir_method_info.cc:104] Check failed: invoke_type == kVirtual (invoke_type=direct, kVirtual=virtual) 
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting...
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Aborting thread:
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up)
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xac2cf200
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=12617 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb2b2b930
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0xb2a2e000-0xb2a30000 stackSize=1018KB
08-23 08:56:32.176 12612-12617/soap.watersmith.ua.soap A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

Весь лог на pastebin по ссылке:
http://pastebin.com/Fe1z4FrP

Поменял в манифесте targetSDK на 23, (до этого был 17)
Объем лога при падении существенно уменьшился. 
Более того, иногда падение происходит не сразу, после получения ответа сервера, а чуток позже, вот как на скрине:
http://prnt.sc/c9dop4

Comment: Посмотрите через дебаггер, что содержится в ответе. try{
       transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope, headers)
            SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.toString();
         }

Comment: try - cath не помог, сразу после transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope, headers); на SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse(); происходит вылет. в cath ошибка не попадает.

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, "падает" не java-код, а сама виртуальная машина, т.е. это баг в эмуляторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Судя по тексту ошибки, "падает" не java-код, а сама виртуальная
>   машина, т.е. это баг в эмуляторе. – [Roman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183980/roman) 55 мин. назад

Проблема действительно была в эмуляторе. Друзья, не повторяйте моих ошибок, не игнорируйте просьбы студии обновиться.
После обновления "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image 23" с ревизии 7 на 16!
Всё заработало.